# Algorithm to select a best combination from two list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, combinations

I have a search result from two way flight. So, there are two lists that contain the departure flights and arrival flights such as:

- The departure flights list has 20 flights.
- The arrival flights list has 30 flights

So, I will have 600 (20*30) combination between departure flight and arrival flight. I will call the combination list is the **result list**

However, I just want to select a limitation from 600 combination. For instance, I will select the best of 100 flight combination. The criteria to combine the flights is the cheap price for departure and arrival flight.

To do that, I will sort the **result list** by the total price of departure and arrival flight. And I then pick up the first 100 elements from **result list** to get what I want.

But, if the departure flights list has 200 flights and arrival flights list has 300 flights, I will have the **result list** with 60.000 elements. For that reason, I will sort a list with 60.000 elements to find the best 100 elements.

So, there is any an algorithm to select the best combinations as my case.

Thank you so much.

Comment: If the total price is your only criteria (and you can combine any arrival with any departure). Can't you just sort each list by price and take the cheapest?

Comment: If departure date is difference arrival date, I can combine any arrival with any departure. If two dates are the same, I can only combine the departure date time that before the arrival date time. In addition, I don't sort each list. I will sort the result list by  the total price

Comment: Are there any other constraints? e.g. at least X days between the departure and the arrival? Are all the N*M combinations valid?

Comment: @GaborSch At least X days between the departure and the arrival is not important

Comment: Excuse me but, what is the question?

Comment: Can you put all the additional requirements into your question? Still not clear about your question.

Comment: @PhamTrung all the additional requirements is not important. But if the departure and arrival are the same date, departure time of the outward flight and arrival time of return flight are required

Comment: @ThinhPhan so the departure time is always less than or equal to arrival time in all flights?

Comment: @PhamTrung you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% clear from your question, but I understand that you are looking for a faster algorithm to find a certain number of best / cheapest combinations of departure and arrival flights.

You can do this *much faster* by sorting the lists of departure and arrival flights individually by cost and then using a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_data_structure) for expanding the next-best combinations one-by-one until you have enough.

Here's the full algorithm -- in Python, but without using any special libraries, just standard data structures, so this should be easily transferable to any other language:

```py
NUM_FLIGHTS, NUM_BEST = 1000, 100

# create test data: each entry corresponds to just the cost of one flight
from random import randint
dep = sorted([randint(1, 100) for i in range(NUM_FLIGHTS)])
arr = sorted([randint(1, 100) for i in range(NUM_FLIGHTS)])
def is_compatible(i, j): # for checking constraints, e.g. timing of flights
    return True          # but for now, assume no constraints

# get best combination using sorted lists and heap
from heapq import heappush, heappop
heap = [(dep[0] + arr[0], 0, 0)]   # initial: best combination from dep and arr
result = []                        # the result list
visited = set()                    # make sure not to add combinations twice
while heap and len(result) < NUM_BEST:
    cost, i, j = heappop(heap)     # get next-best combination
    if (i, j) in visited: continue # did we see those before? skip
    visited.add((i, j))
    if is_compatible(i, j):        # if 'compatible', add to results
        result.append((cost, dep[i], arr[j]))
    # add 'adjacent' combinations to the heap
    if i < len(dep) - 1:           # next-best departure + same arrival
        heappush(heap, (dep[i+1] + arr[j], i+1, j))
    if j < len(arr) - 1:           # same departure + next-best arrival
        heappush(heap, (dep[i] + arr[j+1], i, j+1))
print result

# just for testing: compare to brute-force (get best from all combinations)
comb = [(d, a) for d in dep for a in arr]
best = sorted((d+a, d, a) for (d, a) in comb)[:NUM_BEST]
print best
print result == best # True -> same results as brute force (just faster)
```

This works roughly like this:

- sort both the departure flights `dep` and the arrival flights `arr` by their cost
- create a heap and put the best combination (best departure and best arrival) as well as the corresponding indices in their lists into the heap: `(dep[0] + arr[0], 0, 0)`
- repeat until you have enough combinations or there are no more elements in the heap:

  - pop the best element from the heap (sorted by total cost)
  - if it satisfies the contraints, add it to the result set
  - make sure you do not add flights twice to the result set, using `visited` set
  - add the two 'adjacent' combinations to the heap, i.e. taking the same flight from `dep` and the next from `arr`, and the next from `dep` and the same from `arr`, i.e. `(dep[i+1] + arr[j], i+1, j)` and `(dep[i] + arr[j+1], i, j+1)`

Here's a very small worked example. The axes are (the costs of) the `dep` and `arr` flights, and the entries in the table are in the form `n(c)m`, where `n` is the iteration that entry was added to the `heap` (if it is at all), `c` is the cost, and `m` is the iteration it was added to the 'top 10' `result` list (if any).

```
dep\arr     1       3       4       6       7
   2      0(3)1   1(5)4   4(6)8   8(8)-     -
   2      1(3)2   2(5)6   6(6)9   9(8)-     -
   3      2(4)3   3(6)7   7(7)-     -       -
   4      3(5)5   5(7)-     -       -       -
   6      5(7)10    -       -       -       -

Result: (1,2), (1,2), (1,3), (3,2), (1,4), (3,2), (3,3), (2,4), (2,4), (1,6)
```

Note how the sums in both the columns and the rows of the matrix are always increasing, so the best results can always be found in a somewhat triangular area in the top-left. Now the idea is that if your currently best combination (the one that's first in the heap) is `dep[i], arr[i]`, then there's no use in checking, e.g., combination `dep[i+2], arr[i]` before checking `dep[i+1], arr[i]`, which must have a lower total cost, so you add `dep[i+1], arr[i]` (and likewise `dep[i], arr[i+1]`) to the heap, and repeat with popping the next element from the heap.

---

I compared the results of this algorithm to the results of your brute-force approach, and the resulting flights are the same, i.e. the algorithm works, and *always yields the optimal result*. Complexity should be *O(n log(n))* for sorting the departure and arrival lists (*n* being the number of flights in those original lists), plus *O(m log(m))* for the heap-loop (*m* iterations with *log(m)* work per iteration, *m* being the number of elements in the result list).

This finds the best *1,000* combinations of *100,000* departure and *100,000* arrival flights (for a total of *1,000,000,000,000* possible combinations) in *less than one second*.

Note that those numbers are for the case that you have no additional constraints, i.e. each departure flight can be combined with each arrival flight. If there are constraints, you can use the `is_compatible` function sketched in the above code to check those and to skip that pairing. This means, that for each incompatible pair with low total cost, the loop needs one additional iteration. This means that in the *worst case*, for example if there are *no compatible pairs at all*, or when the only compatible pairs are those with the highest total cost, the algorithm could in fact expand *all* the combination.

On average, though, this should not be the case, and the algorithm should perform rather quickly.

Comment: I think you should examine only the matching flights (i.e. one has to arrive before he goes back).

Comment: @user189 Of course, that's what I meant with "other checks as needed", but to keep it simple, my "flights" are just the costs and nothing else.

Comment: Sorry if I sound rude, but in the worst case, the complexity would be something like N*M*log(N*M)?

Comment: @user189 How so? And what is N and M in your comment? Sorting the original lists is O(nlogn), n being the length of the dep and arr lists, and then another O(mlogm) for the heap search, m being the number of flights in the result set.

Comment: @tobias_k (I was meaning N departures and M arrivals) If most of the combinations (aka the best) are impossible, you will iterate through all of them and only at the end get the (best) possible combinations?

Comment: @user189 Ah, now I understand. In this case, you can sort the departures, and then add a hashmap {departure -> sorted compatible arrivals} and then just use those.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure this hashmap is a great idea here. You would basically have to store most of the pairs and it doesn't use the property that if an arrival is compatible for a departure, it is for all previous departures. I will try to get something out of that.

Comment: @user189 Agreed, this was rather hastily written down. But before I spend more though on this, let's wait whether OP really needs it... ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k thank you so much. Actually, there are not only some other constraints to combine two flights, but also there are a lot of lists flight in case of connecting flight. But you give me a general solution to resolve my issue. I will also use some other heuristics to do my problem. Btw, I know some programming languages such as Python, Java, PHP, C++, etc. So, your code is very clear

Comment: @ThinhPhan:This solution doesn't give you a guarantee to find the best combinations. It's a just a heuristic. I wonder why this isn't explained better. Sorry, but this is very poor quality!

Comment: @Phpdna Seriously? AGAIN? This is _not_ a heuristic. It works. I tried it. I explained it over and over. If you do not like or understand my answer, just leave it for OP to decide (remember?). How about improving your own 'answer' instead?

Comment: @tobias_k:And what if the limit number results is smaller then the worst case? Did it find the best combinations? Why don't write it upfront? I have asked you many times and sadly it's all deleted!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be using some SQL statements to do the Cartesian product. You can apply any kind of filters, based on the data itself, ordering, range selection, etc. Something like this:

```
SELECT d.time as dep_time, a.time as arr_time, d.price+a.price as total_price
FROM departures d, arrivals a
WHERE a.time > d.time + X
ORDER BY d.price+a.price
LIMIT 0,100
```

Actually `X` can be even 0, but arrival should happen AFTER the departure anyways.

Why I would choose SQL:

- It's closest to the data itself, you don't have to query them
- It's highly optimized, if you use indexes, I'm sure you can't beat its performance with your own code
- It's simple and declarative :)

Comment: I think it's because he wants to know how to have a efficient solution and you don't explain how indexes would help there.

Comment: Actually each database server uses the indexes differently. There is no general explanation. My statement is, that all major database vendors have spent many thousands of hours to optimize the operations, which is probably much more effective than a junior-to-medium programmer *alone* can do. Of course, I cannot estimate the complexity of these algorithms, and the SQL is optimized rather for execution time or memory allocation than for theoretical algorithmic complexity.

Comment: I'm not sure if you serious. 15 Millions of rows in mysql? And what indexes are you talking about?

Comment: @Phpdna OK, you didn't understand my statement. First, I didn't talk about MySQL (although I used MySQL syntax, for easy understanding). Oracle, MSSQL, PGSQL are more optimized than MySQL. Second, 15 Million is just a ROWSET, not a table. We don't store it, just generate it by the query. Actually there are optimization techniques for `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`/`TOP` that the SQL executors can apply. Third, I was talking about indexes on arrivals and departure data (the source data), if they're part of a big table, we  can leave out irrelevant data from the calculation (also vendor dependent).

Comment: Just in case with worst case you need those 15M. But I'm out. Thanks for reading.

Comment: OK, I made a measurement, on my very slow laptop, with MySQL, withot any optimization, 4000x4000 product (which is 16M) runs around 4.5 seconds. `EXPLAIN` shows no optimization, although I think Oracle or MSSQL would be able to optimize.

Comment: At first I thought this would be overkill, but then again, the flight data probably comes from a data base anyway... +1 from me.

Comment: @GaborSch:Maybe you are right but then you depends on their mood and they often stinks and often you don't speak with technicians or only half-technicians!