# Coin exchange algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm building a poker game. In my application I have a class `ChipSet`. A `ChipSet` is basically an array of 5 ints (one for each color poker chip).

```
public class ChipSet {

    public static final int WHITE_VALUE = 1;
    public static final int RED_VALUE = 2;
    public static final int GREEN_VALUE = 5;
    public static final int BLUE_VALUE = 10;
    public static final int BLACK_VALUE = 20;

    public static final int[] VALUES = new int[]{WHITE_VALUE, RED_VALUE, GREEN_VALUE, BLUE_VALUE, BLACK_VALUE};

    protected int[] chips;

    public ChipSet(int[] chips) {
        if (chips == null || chips.length != 5)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ChipSets should contain exactly 5 integers!");

        // store a copy of passed array
        this.chips = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.chips.length; i++) {
            this.chips[i] = chips[i];
        }
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return chips[0] * WHITE_VALUE +
                chips[1] * RED_VALUE +
                chips[2] * GREEN_VALUE +
                chips[3] * BLUE_VALUE +
                chips[4] * BLACK_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Now what if I have for example a `ChipSet` with an array `[0,0,2,1,0]` (5+5+10 = 20) and I want to use my `ChipSet` to pay something that costs 16 units. I would have to exchange chips to make this possible.

What I need is an algorithm that exchanges as efficient as possible (exchange as few chips as possible) to make such a payment possible. A payment would just subtract the amount of chips from the array so the leftovers will still be in the `ChipSet` after the payment. How would I do this?

What I need is this kind of method:

```
public boolean exchangeToMakeAvailable(int goal) {
    // algorithm to exchange chips as efficient as possible

    // store the new values in the array, making sure the sum is still the same

    // return whether it has succeeded (false when the sum is less than the requested amount)
}
```

Would greatly appreciate it if you could help me figure this out.

For example:

Before the algorithm I have a ChipSet with an array `[0,0,2,1,0]` which has a sum of 20. I want to pay something that costs 16 units. After using the algorithm, I would have the most efficient exchange as possible, in this case the algorithm would change the array to `[1,2,1,1,0]` which also has a sum of 20, but now I can make a payment of 16. After the payment the `ChipSet` would have the array `[0,2,0,0,0]`.

I hope my problem is clear and if it's not, leave a comment and I will explain further.

Comment: Could you give us some examples--i.e. if `chips` is `[0,0,2,1,0]` on input and `goal` is 16, what would `chips` be afterwards and what would the function result be?  And possibly other similar examples.  Sorry, but the problem statement isn't quite clear to me.

Comment: Excelent question! It's a great algorithm exercise!

Comment: I have added an example with pre and post conditions.

Comment: The unclear part for me is "as efficient as possible (exchange as few chips as possible)" - reading that literally, I believe you can always solve it by exchanging your most valuable chip. So, what exactly is your cost function? Number of chips given and received? Number of chips remaining after transaction?...

Comment: I don't get why [1,2,1,1,0] is better then [0,0,2,1,0]. Why can't you go from [0,0,2,1,0] to [0,2,0,0,0]? Something like [0,0,2,1,0] - 16 = [0,2,0,0,0]! I personally go to the inverse: make a chipset with the less number of chips as possible: [0,0,2,1,0] (20) = [0,0,0,2,0] (20). So you can do operations (plus/minus) as any other number base.

Comment: Amadan, I understand that that part is unclear. By "as efficient as possible", I mean the number of chips given and received should be as low as possible.

Comment: Good point Christian, that would indeed also be a valid solution, would greatly appreciate any help on the implementation

Comment: So your chipset is basicly used to calculate the total value of the players chips? If your question is like this: "How do I calculate what chips two parties have to exchange in order to get a succesful trade.

Comment: What is your definition of 'cost'? Let's consider following case: You have [0,0,2,1,0] chips (5+5+10 = 20) and pay 4 unit from that. There are several choices, (a) exchange one GreenChip(5) to five WhiteChips(1x5) then pay four of them and keep one, (b)  exchange one GreenChip(5) to two RedChips(2x2) and one WhiteChip(1) then pay two Reds and keep one White, etc. All of them have 'exchange one Coin, GreenChip(5) or BlueChip(10)' in common. Is the cost of all choices are same, 'exchange one coin'?

Comment: I think you should always work with your "total". So: you have 20 and want to discount -16 from your total. The way you "present" the total of chips is irrelevant, as long as it is correct! I would implement a function to "normalize" the total in chip array, always using less chips as possible!

Comment: The user sees a graphical overview of 5 piles of chips. If the height of the piles change a lot all the time, it will confuse the user, which is what I want to avoid. That is why I want the algorithm to exchange as few chips as possible.

Comment: you need to define what you want as "optimal" before we can help i think. IMHO It might be easier to calculate according to "lowest number of chips required to display current total" versus thinking about exchanging.

Comment: btw, the above IS how your standard blackjack game decides what coins to display

Comment: @Christian If you're interested I have a solution posted which could be fun to read.

Comment: OK, I'll check it out!

Comment: @Christian If you're still interested I completely reworked my answer to a compile ready solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is an edit, I completely reworked my answer.**

**Problem from game perspective **
The player has 2 green chips (5 points) and 1 blue (10 points). This totals 20 points. Now the player want to buy a ingame icon that costs 16 points. The player has enough money to buy the item. So the player pays 16 points, but what points will he give to the shop to pay correctly.

Now I've written a working example with all of the work done.

**Code**

Program.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Setting up test environment
        Player player = new Player("Borrie", new int[]{0,0,0,0, 230});
        int itemCost = 16626;
        // Pay for item
        System.out.printf("First we check if the player can pay with it's current ChipSet");
        if (!player.canPayWithChipSet(player.getChips(), 5)) {
            if (player.exchangeChips(5)) {
                System.out.printf("\n\nThe players ChipSet:" + Arrays.toString(player.getChips().chips));
                System.out.printf("\nThe players ChipSet has been succesfully exchanged.");
            } else {
                System.out.printf("\n\nThe players ChipSet:" + Arrays.toString(player.getChips().chips));
                System.out.printf("\nThe players ChipSet was not able to be exchanged.\n");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.printf("\n\nThe player can pay exact with it's original ChipSet. No need to exchange.");
        }

    }
}
```

Player.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Player {

    private String name;
    private ChipSet chips;
    private int points = 0;

    public Player(String name, int[] chips) {
        this.name = name;
        this.chips = new ChipSet(chips);
        this.points = this.chips.getSum();
    }

    public boolean exchangeChips(int cost) {
        ChipSet newChipSet = exchangePlayerChipSet(this.chips.getChips(), cost);
        if (newChipSet == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            this.chips = newChipSet;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ChipSet exchangePlayerChipSet(int[] originalChipValues, int cost) {
        ChipSet newChipSet = null;
        // Create possible combinations to compare
        ArrayList<ChipSet> chipSetCombos = createCombinations(this.chips.getChips());
        // Filter the chipset based on if it's able to pay without changing chips
        System.out.printf("\n\n---- Filter which of these combinations are able to be payed with without changing chips ----");
        ArrayList<ChipSet> filteredCombos = filterCombinations(chipSetCombos, cost);
        // Compare the filtered chipsets to determine which one has changed the least
        if (!filteredCombos.isEmpty()) {
            newChipSet = compareChipSets(originalChipValues, filteredCombos);
        }
        return newChipSet;
    }

    private ArrayList<ChipSet> createCombinations(int[] array) {
        ArrayList<ChipSet> combos = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] startCombo = array;
        System.out.printf("Player has " + getTotalPoints(startCombo) + " points in chips.");
        System.out.printf("\nPlayer has these chips (WHITE,RED,GREEN,BLUE,BLACK): " + Arrays.toString(startCombo));

        while (startCombo[4] != 0) {
            startCombo = lowerBlack(startCombo);
            if (getTotalPoints(startCombo) == points) {
                combos.add(new ChipSet(startCombo));
            }
        }
        while (startCombo[3] != 0) {
            startCombo = lowerBlue(startCombo);
            if (getTotalPoints(startCombo) == points) {
                combos.add(new ChipSet(startCombo));
            }
        }
        while (startCombo[2] != 0) {
            startCombo = lowerGreen(startCombo);
            if (getTotalPoints(startCombo) == points) {
                combos.add(new ChipSet(startCombo));
            }
        }
        while (startCombo[1] != 0) {
            startCombo = lowerRed(startCombo);
            if (getTotalPoints(startCombo) == points) {
                combos.add(new ChipSet(startCombo));
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("\n\n---- Creating variations on the players chips ----");
        System.out.printf("\nVariation (all worth " + getTotalPoints(startCombo) + " points):\n");
        int teller = 1;
        for (ChipSet a : combos) {
            System.out.printf("\nCombo " + teller + ": " + Arrays.toString(a.getChips()));
            teller++;
        }
        return combos;
    }

    private ArrayList<ChipSet> filterCombinations(ArrayList<ChipSet> combinations, int cost) {
        ArrayList<ChipSet> filteredChipSet = new ArrayList<>();
        combinations.stream().filter((cs) -> (canPayWithChipSet(cs, cost))).forEach((cs) -> {
            filteredChipSet.add(cs);
        });
        return filteredChipSet;
    }

    // This method has be worked out
    public boolean canPayWithChipSet(ChipSet cs, int cost) {
        ChipSet csOrig = new ChipSet(cs.chips);
        ChipSet csCopy = new ChipSet(cs.chips);
        int counterWhite = 0;
        int counterRed = 0;
        int counterGreen = 0;
        int counterBlue = 0;
        int counterBlack = 0;

        while (20 <= cost && cost > 0 && csOrig.getChips()[4] != 0) {
            csOrig.getChips()[4] -= 1;
            cost -= 20;
            counterBlack++;
        }
        while (10 <= cost && cost > 0 && csOrig.getChips()[3] != 0) {
            csOrig.getChips()[3] -= 1;
            cost -= 10;
            counterBlue++;
        }
        while (5 <= cost && cost > 0 && csOrig.getChips()[2] != 0) {
            csOrig.getChips()[2] -= 1;
            cost -= 5;
            counterGreen++;
        }
        while (2 <= cost && cost > 0 && csOrig.getChips()[1] != 0) {
            csOrig.getChips()[1] -= 1;
            cost -= 2;
            counterRed++;
        }
        while (1 <= cost && cost > 0 && csOrig.getChips()[0] != 0) {
            csOrig.getChips()[0] -= 1;
            cost -= 1;
            counterWhite++;
        }
        if (cost == 0){
            System.out.printf("\nCombo: %s can pay exact. With %d white, %d red, %d green, %d blue an %d black chips", Arrays.toString(csCopy.chips),counterWhite,counterRed,counterGreen,counterBlue,counterBlack);
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("\nCombo: %s cannot pay exact.\n\n\n", Arrays.toString(csCopy.chips));
            return false;
        }    
    }

    private ChipSet compareChipSets(int[] originalChipValues, ArrayList<ChipSet> chipSetCombos) {
        ChipSet newChipSet;
        int[] chipSetWaardes = originalChipValues; // originele chipset aantal van kleur
        int[] chipSetCombosDifferenceValues = new int[chipSetCombos.size()];
        int teller = 1;

        System.out.printf("\n\n---- Calculate differences between players stack and it's variations ----");
        for (ChipSet cs : chipSetCombos) {
            int aantalWhite = cs.getChips()[0];
            int aantalRed = cs.getChips()[1];
            int aantalGreen = cs.getChips()[2];
            int aantalBlue = cs.getChips()[3];
            int aantalBlack = cs.getChips()[4];
            int differenceWhite = Math.abs(chipSetWaardes[0] - aantalWhite);
            int differenceRed = Math.abs(chipSetWaardes[1] - aantalRed);
            int differenceGreen = Math.abs(chipSetWaardes[2] - aantalGreen);
            int differenceBlue = Math.abs(chipSetWaardes[3] - aantalBlue);
            int differenceBlack = Math.abs(chipSetWaardes[4] - aantalBlack);
            int totalDifference = differenceWhite + differenceRed + differenceGreen + differenceBlue + differenceBlack;
            chipSetCombosDifferenceValues[teller - 1] = totalDifference;
            System.out.printf("\nCombo " + teller + ": " + Arrays.toString(cs.getChips()) + " = " + totalDifference);
            teller++;
        }
        newChipSet = chipSetCombos.get(smallestValueOfArrayIndex(chipSetCombosDifferenceValues));
        System.out.printf("\n\nThe least different ChipSet is: " + Arrays.toString(newChipSet.getChips()) + " ");
        return newChipSet;
    }

    private int smallestValueOfArrayIndex(int[] array) {
        int huidigeWaarde = array[0];
        int smallestIndex = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] < huidigeWaarde) {
                huidigeWaarde = array[j];
                smallestIndex = j;
            }
        }
        return smallestIndex;
    }

    private int[] lowerBlack(int[] array) {
        return new int[]{array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3] + 2, array[4] - 1};
    }

    private int[] lowerBlue(int[] array) {
        return new int[]{array[0], array[1], array[2] + 2, array[3] - 1, array[4]};
    }

    private int[] lowerGreen(int[] array) {
        return new int[]{array[0] + 1, array[1] + 2, array[2] - 1, array[3], array[4]};
    }

    private int[] lowerRed(int[] array) {
        return new int[]{array[0] + 2, array[1] - 1, array[2], array[3], array[4]};
    }

    private int getTotalPoints(int[] array) {
        return ((array[0] * 1) + (array[1] * 2) + (array[2] * 5) + (array[3] * 10) + (array[4] * 20));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }

    public ChipSet getChips() {
        return chips;
    }

}
```

ChipSet.java

```
public class ChipSet {

    public static final int WHITE_VALUE = 1;
    public static final int RED_VALUE = 2;
    public static final int GREEN_VALUE = 5;
    public static final int BLUE_VALUE = 10;
    public static final int BLACK_VALUE = 20;

    public static final int[] VALUES = new int[]{WHITE_VALUE, RED_VALUE, GREEN_VALUE, BLUE_VALUE, BLACK_VALUE};

    protected int[] chips;

    public ChipSet(int[] chips) {
        if (chips == null || chips.length != 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ChipSets should contain exactly 5 integers!");
        }

        // store a copy of passed array
        this.chips = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.chips.length; i++) {
            this.chips[i] = chips[i];
        }
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return chips[0] * WHITE_VALUE
                + chips[1] * RED_VALUE
                + chips[2] * GREEN_VALUE
                + chips[3] * BLUE_VALUE
                + chips[4] * BLACK_VALUE;
    }

    public int[] getChips() {
        return this.chips;
    }
}
```

Some explanation:

- *Create combinations*

> We create some submethods the trade a chip in for it's lower chip. So
>   for example black = 2 blues. Then we create 5 loops in order. The
>   first ones checks if there are still black chips, if so reduce 1 black
>   add 2 blues. Save this new combination in a list if the sum of the
>   chips in the new ChipSet equals the original ChipSets value. Loop
>   continues until there are no blacks anymore. Then it check if there
>   are blues and repeats the same process until there are no reds
>   anymore. Now we have list with all possible variations of X value in
>   chips.

- *Filter combinations*

> You filter the ChipSets based on
>   if you can pay X points with them without exchanging. We loop over all
>   possible combinations of ChipSets created in the previous part. If you
>   can pay with the ChipSet without exchanging add it to the filteredList
>   of ChipSets. The result is a filered list with only valid ChipSets.

- *Calculate difference*

> For each ChipSet we count the number of chips of all colors in a
>   ChipSet and substract the original chipset number of chips with it.
>   You take the absolute value of that and make a sum of all those
>   differences of the original and the combos colors. Now we have a
>   number that represents the difference from the original. Now all we
>   have to do is compare all the ChipSets ´difference number´. The one
>   with the least difference we use to assign to the player.

**Simple huh**

Comment: Took me a while, but had fun making it :) Exact implementation is up to you but the algorithm is in there.

Comment: About the optimal exchange,you want as little movement as possible. So give the biggest chips possible. Fewer chips = fewer movement.

Comment: Your algorithm does not maintain the sum! It returns a `ChipSet` with a sum of `pointsToExchange`.

Comment: Hold on. I just woke up. What do you mean with maintain the sum? If you can explain in Dutch.

Comment: After the algorithm, the result of getSum() should be the same as before the algorithm.

Comment: So the method should just calculate 'what' chips to return but not substract the chips yet. E.g actually pay yet

Comment: The algorithm should change the chips in a way that makes the purchase possible, without changing the total. E.g. when I have [0,0,2,1,0] (=20) and I want to pay 16, it should change to [1,2,1,1,0] (=20).

Comment: Why would you want to just exchange the chips? This means your not only just using this method to pay for an item right? Otherwise there would be no need to all the hassle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67718/discussion-between-mark-buikema-and-manyquestions).

Comment: I've added a new solution on top of the first one.

Comment: @MarkBuikema Added the final algorithm o make the task complete, you should give it a run. It now checks first if the current ChipSet can be used to pay and returns a boolean just like you asked. If it can it doesn't do anything, otherwise it goes through the 3 sub-algorithms and defines the best ChipSet (one to able to use to pay and least different one) and changes the players ChipSet the it.

Comment: @MarkBuikema And hows the progress?

Comment: @MarkBuikema If need any changes, or improvements on the speed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a binpacking. Sort the chips and pick the best fit. Then compute how many its left and either trade a chip or rinse and repeat.

Comment: It's an algorithm that tries to solve the problem of finding the most optimal number/size/position of items as if those items were being packed into a bin.

Comment: Can you explain a little more detailed?

Comment: @MarkBuikema:Binpacking is very fast it better when you have too many points. You can also try to sort the combinations and find only nearby combinations:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011551/algorithm-to-select-a-best-combination-from-two-list/25012268#25012268.